# What is the notation about group differences in terms standard deviations?

Tags: measurement, personality, statistics, test

I am just getting into watching psych lectures and things online and am taking notes but I have been wondering what the proper/standard way of writing in note form about standard deviations is.

For example: GROUP-A is a third of a standard deviation higher in TRAIT than GROUP-B.

Is there a standardised way of representing that information with a kind of notation or shorthand in psychology?

Thanks! And sorry for the very basic question!

Answer (score 1):

The psychology notation for standardized differences between group means is *d*. I.e., the difference between group differences divided by the within-group standard deviation. Note that there are some variants about which group is used or whether a pooled standard deviation is obtained.

I.e., in your example: *d* = 0.3.

If you want to report means and sds, then you typically use *M* and *SD*.